# How to optimize Sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, performance, sequelize.js

Sequelize is running simple query, and it's taking over 35ms.

I've tried optimize query, because phpMyAdmin took over 0.4ms. I know - Sequelize has ORM, but it can't to took 34,6ms.

MySql table has 16 rows and 12 columns.
phpMyAdmin query:

```sql
SELECT `is_paid`, `page` FROM `i_items_pages` AS `ItemPage` WHERE `ItemPage`.`item_id` = 1 AND `ItemPage`.`page` = 1
```

It took 0.4ms.
item_id and page are index.

Node app:

server.js

```
mysql = require('./app/models')
global.sqlCon = mysql
```

ItemPageRepository.js

```
async findAll() { 
        try {

            const start = performance.now()
            const result = await sqlCon 
                .ItemPage 
                .findAll({
                    where: this._whereClause(),
                    attributes: [
                        'is_paid',
                        'page'
                    ]
                })
                const total = performance.now() - start
                console.log(`rep blocked for ${total}.`)
            return result
        } catch(e) {
            logger.error( e)
            this._next()
        }
    }

_whereClause(){
        if (this._isFullArticle) {
            return {
                item_id: this._articleId
            }
        } else {
            return {
                item_id: this._articleId,
                page: this._pageId
            }
        }

    }
```

It took 35ms

ItemPage.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ItemPage = sequelize.define('ItemPage', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT(15),
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    item_id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT(15),
        allowNull: false
    }, 
    page: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: true
    }, 
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }, 
    article: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }, 
    is_published: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        allowNull: false
    }, 
    is_paid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        defaultValue: 0
    }, 
    reads: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        defaultValue: 0
    }, 
    views: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    underscored: true, 
    tableName: 'i_items_pages'
  })

  ItemPage.associate = (models) => {
    ItemPage.belongsTo(models.Item)
}

  return ItemPage
}
```

I expected to get about 10ms, but actual output 35ms - 47ms.

Comment: you are selecting only 2 columns on mysql query and all the comuns with node.js. Anyway, where is installed the database? in your local env?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon no. In Node I selected two columns too: attributes: [
                        'is_paid',
                        'page'
                    ]

Comment: Thanks I, got answer from other forum. Now query takes 3ms.

Comment: Answer to your question if you solved: this could help someone else 

Comment: yeah, @hdoitc for benefit of others please leave an update with the answer or link to where you found the answer. thanks.

Comment: I use Sequelize models, and repositories. In each repository I called mysql connect. It tooks about 30ms. But mysql connect need to write into Sequelize config `sequelize.authenticate()`

Comment: @hdoitc Would you be able to add a link to that forum or add a sample index file and model file?